Error in compilation with named source file
I have this program NOT saved with a name:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
            \foreach \j 
            [evaluate=\j as \h using {int(12*rnd)}, 
            evaluate=\j as \m using {int(60*rnd)}]
            in {1,...,3} {
                \node[font={\clockfont\ClockStyle=1\ClockFrametrue\Huge}] at (2*\i,2*\j) {\clock{\h}{\m}};
                \node at (2*\i,2*\j+1) {\h$:$ \m};
            }   
        }   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It compile correclly with this result:

BUT if I compile (TeXSTudio last version) with ANY name I have no result and this error of compilation:

Why?
LOG FILE:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4) (format=lualatex 2024.11.26)  28 NOV 2024 11:40
 restricted system commands enabled.
**"senza titolo1.tex"
("./senza titolo1.tex"
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/f
ontloader-2023-08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'.
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.c
ls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.c
fg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
) (C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: File not foun
d: "lmroman10-regular".)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds
.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.s
ty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
\sa@box=\box51
) (C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/clock/clock.sty
Package: clock 2001/04/10 v0.1 TeXclock

(./clock.tex

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \documentclass[border=1cm]{
                             standalone}
The document may only declare one class.


(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.
sty
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.st
y
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil
-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks20
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen140
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen141
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil
-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box52
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.
code.tex
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.
sty
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.c
fg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.
sty
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
s.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys
.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys
libraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count196
\c@pgf@countb=\count197
\c@pgf@countc=\count198
\c@pgf@countd=\count199
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count266

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.c
fg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
s-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
s-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
ssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count267
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count268
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
sprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 274.
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
e.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code
.tex
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.
code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparse
r.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen154
\pgfmath@count=\count269
\pgfmath@box=\box53
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.basic.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.random.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.base.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.round.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.misc.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.
code.tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat
.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270
))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.
tex)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
epoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen156
\pgf@picminy=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@xx=\dimen163
\pgf@xy=\dimen164
\pgf@yx=\dimen165
\pgf@yy=\dimen166
\pgf@zx=\dimen167
\pgf@zy=\dimen168
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
epathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen169
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen170
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
epathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen171
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen172
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
escopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box54
\pgf@hbox=\box55
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box56
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count271
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
egraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen173
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
etransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen174
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen176
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
equick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
eobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
epathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
earrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen177
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
eshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen178
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count272
\pgf@shadingcount=\count273
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
eimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
eexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box57
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
elayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
etransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
epatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
erdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodule
shapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box58
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodule
plot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfco
mp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen179
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen180
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfco
mp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.st
y
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys
.code.tex))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code
.tex))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.
code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen181
\pgffor@skip=\dimen182
\pgffor@stack=\toks30
\pgffor@toks=\toks31
))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibr
aryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count274
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen183
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen184
\tikz@lasty=\dimen185
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen186
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen189
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen190
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen191
\tikz@figbox=\box59
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box60
\tikz@tempbox=\box61
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box62
\tikztreelevel=\count275
\tikznumberofchildren=\count276
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count277
\tikz@fig@count=\count278

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodule
matrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count279
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count280
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count281
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count282

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lua
tex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count283
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
) ("./senza titolo1.aux")
\openout1 = senza titolo1.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4
.

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/clock/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count284
\scratchdimen=\dimen192
\scratchbox=\box64
\nofMPsegments=\count285
\nofMParguments=\count286
\everyMPshowfont=\toks32
\MPscratchCnt=\count287
\MPscratchDim=\dimen193
\MPnumerator=\count288
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count289
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks33
)
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-b
ase.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/epstopdf-sys.c
fg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
)) [1

]

! LaTeX hooks Error: Missing \PopDefaultHookLabel.
(hooks)              The label 'clock' was pushed but never popped.
(hooks)              Something is wrong.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.25 \end{document}
                 

LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.

Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.


("./senza titolo1.aux")
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
 ***********
)))
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 3 was incomplete)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 13156 strings out of 476497
 195342,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 75254 words of node memory still in use:
   800 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 3436 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 7733 attribute, 48 gl
ue_spec, 7733 attribute_list, 2 write, 3178 pdf_literal, 796 pdf_colorstack node
s
   avail lists: 2:31,3:6359,4:1602,5:22,6:2,7:6894,9:1618
 34827 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 118i,5n,114p,430b,824s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
Output written on senza titolo1.pdf (1 page, 8308 bytes).

PDF statistics: 9 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 16 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)


Compiles just fine for me. Please provide the actual log file, not the filtered log from TeXStudio, that filtered look is often wrong.

show your log up to the error, it will have found some local file with bad markup

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.1 \documentclass[border=1cm]{
standalone}
The document may only declare one class.

do not name your tex file clock.tex, clock.sty contains a \input clock.tex and will try to input your own tex file again.

I used different names (no clock.tex) and I have the same errors (pdfLatex, LuaTex, or XeLaTeX)

show your log, that will show exactly which file has the error. but what Ulrike says is almost certainly what is happening. (most commonly this is seen if people make pstricks.tex)

Even if you use another file name, have you let a file clock.tex in your working directory? Delete it or try in a new empty directory.

@jlab I would guess yes:-) (but the log would stop us guessing)

@DavidCarlisle  You are right!!! I have in the same directory one old file named clock.tex. I am sorrrrrrry.

@jlab You are right!!! I have in the same directory one old file named clock.tex. I am sorrrrrrry.

I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.

see literally the line before the error message that you showed is `(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/clock/clock.sty
Package: clock 2001/04/10 v0.1 TeXclock
(./clock.tex
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.
`  showing the context is a clock.tex in that directory

@jlab actually I think that's not a good close reason, it's not an uncomon error (with different packages that have the same feature of a tex file beind the package)

@DavidCarlisle You right. I retracted my vote. As you wrote as answer, it's much better.

@jlab Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8778/36296 I would refrain from closing posts as solved in comments because in some situations, this can cause the deletion of the post.

The line before the error message that you originally showed is
(C:/Users/raffa/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/clock/clock.sty
Package: clock 2001/04/10 v0.1 TeXclock
(./clock.tex
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

showing the context is a clock.tex in that directory, removing (or renaming) that file would avoid the error.
